# Monitoring Wildfly with Zabbix

Tags: wildfly, zabbix

Wildfly supports monitoring over `http-remoting-jmx` protocol and Zabbix uses `rmi`. So is it good practise to use "standard" way of specifying JMX (in the Java opts) in the Wildfly? Or how can i achieve monitoring Wildfly using Zabbix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the applications that support remoting-jmx do no not work very well with rmi. You can patch the Java gateway to support remoting-jmx - there are community patches floating around. Keep in mind that it is completely unsupported. This support is supposedly coming with Zabbix 3.4 - see https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1274 .

Comment: So is it better to use Zabbix 3.4 (guess its still in development) or patch version 3.2? If the latter how to actually change sources. I mean the patch from here: https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1274 includes only server and java-gateway changes. What about front-end change?

Comment: Don't use 3.4 at this time unless you know very well what you are doing and are ready to spend a lot of time on that. Patch at that issue does not require frontend changes, although it might not apply to 3.2.

Comment: Hmm... guess i don't understand it then. In that patch, they added a new field called `url` to specify full connection string. If there aren't any frontend changes then how to set it ?

Comment: See https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-1274?focusedCommentId=113596&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-113596 - "If a user macro {$JMX_SERVICE_URL} is specified, then its expanded value is passed to the gateway as the URL to connect to."

Comment: Thank you. Didn't notice that.